# APF, IPTABLES, Fedora 15 - Not blocking correctly

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, fedora

I just got a new remote server which came with Fedora 15.  I first tried to run APF but it gave me this error **"apf(18031): {glob} unable to load iptables module (ip_tables), aborting."**.   Which I then set **SET_MONOKERN="0"** to **SET_MONOKERN="1"** to resolve the problem.

However, with my config file showing

```
BLK_P2P_PORTS="1214,2323,4660_4678,6257,6699,6346,6347,6881_6889,6346,7778"
```

The ports show up as closed, instead of being filtered.  Any idea why this would be happening?

```
22/tcp   open   ssh
80/tcp   open   http
443/tcp  open   https
2323/tcp closed 3d-nfsd
4662/tcp closed edonkey
6346/tcp closed gnutella
6699/tcp closed napster
6881/tcp closed bittorrent-tracker
7778/tcp closed interwise
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't running services on those ports.

Comment: That's my point.  If they are blocked they shouldn't even be coming up as 'closed'.  It's mixed signal.  Kind of seems like still open but without a service running on it.

Comment: So what does your actual firewall look like?

Comment: Sorry not sure what you are asking?  My APF Config?